# Javascript function (with variable information in URL) for a simple GET request

Tags: javascript, forms, get

The situation is as follows:

1. A webpage with two inputs; `input_1` and `input_2`
2. `input_1` is a code to be entered by the user
3. `input_2` is more like a token string, pre-filled or to be filled by user
4. The URL format for the `GET` request is like this: `https://www.apiserver.com/api/v1/static_param_1/input_1/tokens/redeem?token=input_2`

The webpage has a form, which includes a button with an element_id of `button_1`, two text elements with element id's `elem_input_1` and `elem_input_2`.

I need to use javascript to create the GET request which gets fired when the user has input the values and clicked the button.

I tried the following so far.  Any help is highly appreciated:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button_1');

function executeGetReq() { 
  var input_1 = document.getElementById('elem_input_1').value;
  var input_2 = document.getElementById('elem_input_2').value;

  var url = "https://www.apiserver.com/api/v1/static_param_1/" + input_1 + "/tokens/redeem"

  var data = {
    token: input_2,
  };
  $.get(url, data, function (result) {
    if (result == 'ok')
      alert('Success!');
    else
      alert('Failure');
  });
}

button.onclick = executeGetReq;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="elem_input_1" value="input_1"/>
<input id="elem_input_2" value="input_2"/>
<button id="button_1">Go</button>
```

EDIT:

Well, it seems the problem is with CORS.  Still digging.

Comment: Hyphens are not valid in JS variable names

Comment: Phil, Sorry.  I used hyphens to distinguish the variables.  Actual names do not have hyphens in it.  I will change the example with underscores to remove confusion.  Thanks.

Comment: The problem will not be solved like this : as i'd assume you don't have any control on the server side i.e., on `www.apiserver.com`, only the server can decide if it will allow CORS content. To solve this problem, you will have to create a backend that will call `www.apiserver.com` instead, your own backend may have CORS if required, or might host the whole html if required

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the dataType to `jsonp` (But before set it to `json`).

```js
$.get(url, data, function (result) {
    //...
}, 'jsonp');
```

If it doesn't work search for ajax cors on the web.

Or take a look at https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/ajax+cors+error

Comment: Thanks @Xampy I tried both ways, but still same error.  Exploring the helpful links you sent and also looking into server side information.